# How can I display a message in Maven

Tags: java, maven-2

How can I display a message in Maven?

In ant, we do have "echo" to display a message, but in maven, how can I do that?

Comment: Why do you need to do this? What is your use case?

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/echo-maven-plugin/

Comment: @PascalThivent say, if I want to track the value of some property - how can I do that without printing it?

Answer (score 61):

You can use the antrun plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <tasks>
                    <echo>Hello world!</echo>
                </tasks>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

One issue though is that you have to choose what phase of [the build lifecycle](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html) to bind this to (my example has the plugin bound to `generate-resources`). Unlike Ant, you aren't controlling the lifecycle yourself, but rather just binding plugins to certain points in a pre-defined lifecycle. Depending on what you are actually trying to do, this may or may not make sense for your use case.

Comment: see link below for correct sytax:
http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/examples/tasksAttributes.html

Comment: Version is now 3.x.x, it is <target></target> instead of <tasks></tasks>.

Answer (score 18):

You can use [Björn Ekryd](https://github.com/Ekryd)'s [Echo Maven Plugin](https://github.com/Ekryd/echo-maven-plugin), which is published in [Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.github.ekryd.echo-maven-plugin%7Cecho-maven-plugin%7C1.2.0%7Cmaven-plugin):

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.github.ekryd.echo-maven-plugin</groupId>
    <artifactId>echo-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>echo</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <message>war has changed</message>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

---

```
[INFO] --- maven-war-plugin:2.4:war (default-war) @ mymodule ---
[INFO] Packaging webapp
[INFO] Processing war project
[INFO]
[INFO] --- echo-maven-plugin:1.2.0:echo (default) @ mymodule ---
[INFO] war has changed
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Also, this plugin has [95% code coverage](https://coveralls.io/github/Ekryd/echo-maven-plugin), which is pretty cool.

Comment: how did you execute it ?

Comment: I ran `mvn package`, but you can bind it to any [phase](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference) you like.

Comment: Cool, especially that I can use `<fromFile>` to output the content of a file. Just perfect for my needs! This should be the accepted answer (I like to avoid maven-antrun-plugin whenever possible).

Answer (score 13):

You can use [Groovy Maven Plugin](https://groovy.github.io/gmaven/groovy-maven-plugin/) for this.

```
<plugin>                                                         
    <groupId>org.codehaus.gmaven</groupId>                       
    <artifactId>groovy-maven-plugin</artifactId>                 
    <version>2.0</version>                                       
    <executions>                                                 
        <execution>                                              
            <phase>validate</phase>                              
            <goals>                                              
                <goal>execute</goal>                             
            </goals>                                             
            <configuration>                                      
                <source>                                         
                    log.info('Test message: {}', 'Hello, World!')
                </source>                                        
            </configuration>                                     
        </execution>                                             
    </executions>                                                
</plugin>
```

The configuration above will produce the following output:

```
[INFO] Test message: Hello, World!
```

Comment: The maven-antrun-plugin was failing to print messages in maven 3.3.3 in windows. The Groovy plugin worked like a charm.

Comment: Do you know how to print messages when the build does fail? I just want to print a custom message in the end of the build.

Comment: @LenglBoy I cannot answer your question right away, but it worth a separate question, not a comment. It is more about how to detect build failure rather than printing a message.

Answer (score 6):

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <tasks>
                    <echo>[your message]:${Urkey}</echo>
                </tasks>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```