# Maven info statement after command build

Tags: java, maven

I have an maven archetype for my project and I need a simple statement after put build command, e.g. "You have to put groupId, artifactId...".
Is that possible to do this by Maven?

My archetype-descriptor:

```
<archetype-descriptor xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-archetype-plugin/archetype-descriptor/1.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-archetype-plugin/archetype-descriptor/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/archetype-descriptor-1.0.0.xsd"
    name="my-app" partial="false">
<requiredProperties>
    <requiredProperty key="groupId">
        <defaultValue>com.myapp</defaultValue>
    </requiredProperty>
    <requiredProperty key="projectGroupId">
        <defaultValue/>
    </requiredProperty>
    <requiredProperty key="pluginPackageName">
        <defaultValue/>
    </requiredProperty>
</requiredProperties>
<!--
Rest of descriptor
-->

</archetype-descriptor>
```

Comment: If it's just `groupId` and `artifactId`, any maven project would be taken care of for this to be available. Also, do you mean if someone builds a project based on the above archetype using `mvn clean install`, there should be this text displayed?

Comment: I want to print statement. It doesn't matter what. I asked how to configure maven for print simple statement after put command "mvn clean install"

Comment: This might help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3416573/how-can-i-display-a-message-in-maven